# Trouble creating 3D rotation matrix in Pytorch - ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to create 3D rotation matrices in pytorch as seen on the first page of this [pdf](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph216/rotation_12.pdf), but I am encountering some problems. Here is my code so far:

```
zero = torch.from_numpy(np.zeros(len(cos)))
one = torch.from_numpy(np.ones(len(cos)))
R_transpose = torch.tensor([cos, -sin, zero, sin, cos, zero, zero, zero, one]).reshape(-1, 3, 3)
```

The cos and sin are matrices that look like this:

```
tensor([[[1.]],

    [[1.]],

    [[1.]],

    [[1.]],

    [[1.]]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

My goal is to create x number of rotation matrices(e.g. four matrices with the cos values shown above).

The code I currently have results in a "ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars"

How should I change my code to achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you expect us to guess which line produced the error?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use assignment to create `R_transpose`?

```py
# define rotation angels (radians) using numpy
th_np = np.array([np.pi*0.25, np.pi/6, np.pi*0.5, np.pi/3.], dtype=np.float32)
# conver to pytorch
th_t = torch.from_numpy(th_np)
# init to zeros
R_transpose = torch.zeros(th_t.numel(), 3, 3, dtype=torch.float)
# assign the values:
R_transpose[:, 2, 2] = 1.
R_transpose[:, [0,1],[0,1]] = th_t[:, None].cos()
R_transpose[:, 0, 1] = -th_t.sin()
R_transpose[:, 1, 0] = th_t.sin()
```

Resulting with

> ```
> tensor([[[ 7.0711e-01, -7.0711e-01,  0.0000e+00],
>      [ 7.0711e-01,  7.0711e-01,  0.0000e+00],
>      [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]],
>
>     [[ 8.6603e-01, -5.0000e-01,  0.0000e+00],
>      [ 5.0000e-01,  8.6603e-01,  0.0000e+00],
>      [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]],
>
>     [[-4.3711e-08, -1.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
>      [ 1.0000e+00, -4.3711e-08,  0.0000e+00],
>      [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]],
>
>     [[ 5.0000e-01, -8.6603e-01,  0.0000e+00],
>      [ 8.6603e-01,  5.0000e-01,  0.0000e+00],
>      [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]]])
> ```

Note that we assigned all all angels at once, so this solution is applicable to any number of angles you may have.